# Android:Support for unicode characters?

Tags: android

Android doesnt currently support all unicode chars , so some transliterations are impossible to print . What other options are feasible,like would using images for displaying text be scalable ? I have a 1000 word text in devanagari script which I would like to display , i am ok to use the transliteration in english instead of actual glyphs.